# Button that removes all text and add text that I want in Adobe Flash CS5.5

Tags: flash, function, button, text, adobe

please help me. How do I make a button removes all text in a text area and add the text that I want?

I tested with this code. But its not working. 
Here's the code:
`function plpets(e:MouseEvent):void{

this.ItemMenu3.tb3.text = "";

        petList();

}

function petList():void{

        this.ItemMenu3.tb3.text = ("Test 1","Test 2","Test 3");

}`

It only show the "Test 3"

I want it like this pic:
 
[image]

Comment: here is the explanation of why `( , )` returns the last value: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14